# Regex - find part of url and replace to help track PDFs

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I am trying to track PDFs on my site via Google analytics. Using the find and replace in Dreamweaver I need get a regex to find all PDF URLs and add the file name of the PDF onto the end. So:

http://mysite/strategy/annual-plan-16-17.pdf

becomes

http://mysite/strategy/annual-plan-16-17.pdf?pdf=annual-plan-16-17

Unfortunately, though I am learnign REGEX I have not reached this level of sophistication yet, so would be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks ever so much.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970).

Comment: Of course, that is a great suggestion and I have been doing it for some time. At present I can find stuff but not to this level of sophistication unfortunately.

Comment: are you sure you want `http://mysite/strategy/annual-plan.pdf?pdf=annual-plan` and not `http://mysite/strategy/annual-plan-16-17.pdf?pdf=annual-plan-16-17`?

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right, I have corrected the error. More haste less speed. Thanks so much for pointing that out I appreciate it :)

Comment: O, Try `https?://\S*/([^/]+)\.pdf` and replace with `$0?pdf=$1`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I will try it out this afternoon and post of my success :)

Comment: Yes, sure, take your time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use

```
https?://\S*/([^/]+)\.pdf
```

and replace with `$0?pdf=$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WVENbx/1).

**Details**:

- `https?://` - `http://` or `https://`
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace symbols, as many as possible up to the last
- `/` - slash
- `([^/]+)` - (Group 1) one or more chars other than `/`
- `\.pdf` - a literal `.pdf`.

If you need to only grab those links with no `?` after `.pdf`, append `(?!\?)` negative lookahead at the end of the pattern.

In the replacement pattern, the `$0` inserts the whole match text and `$1` inserts only the contents captured into Group 1.

Comment: Such a detailed response is appreciated so much, and really helps with my learning. Thanks, as I mentioned earlier I will try these out and let you know of my success. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3517217 So, did you have enough time to test this out?

Answer (score 0):

This will work well on names separated by '-' and the either any amount of numbers and letters separated by '-', inducing none. It will give you back the letter and numberParts parts with ?pdf= appended to the end of the URL.

```js
var value = "http://mysite/strategy/annual-plan-16-17.pdf";
var matches = value.replace(/([^\/\s]+)(.pdf)/g, "$1$2?pdf=$1");
console.log(matches)
```

This is done by splitting the matching into 2 groups with (), these are:

1. the first one takes the names separated by dashes using [^/\s.]+ to get any number of any character not a '\', '.',or a white-space, this basically gets all the characters from the '.pdf' to the / before it.
2. This next group matches .pdf using .pdf (obviously)
   It then replaces this match with the whole match plus + ?pdf= + the first group.

If you wish jsut the letter part so xxxxx-xxxxx-1111.pdf gose to .pdf?pdf=xxxxx-xxxxx, then you can use this.

```js
var value = "http://mysite/strategy/annual-plan-16-17.pdf";
var matches = value.replace(/([^\/0-9]*[^-\/0-9])(-??[^/.]*)(.pdf)/g, "$1$2$3?pdf=$1");
console.log(matches)
```

This is done by splitting the matching into 3 groups with (), these are:

1. the first one takes the names separated by dashes using [^./0-9]* to get any number of any character not a '.', '/' or a digit, it then uses [^-./0-9] to make sure the match doesn't end with a '-'. This effectively matches words separated by - that don't contain numbers.
2. This group uses -?? to match as few - as possible (including none), it then follows with [^/]* which matches anything that doesn't have a '^' or a '/'. This effectively matches words separated by - that contain numbers.
3. uses .pdf to match .pdf. If you wanted to ensure it was at the end of a string you could use .pdf$

This match is then replaced with itself + ?pdf= + the first matching group.

Comment: I am so grateful how clearly you have set out your reply it is absolutely brilliant as it becomes a learning resource I can use for the future, in the hopes that i will truly get to grips with REGEX like you have. I am really very grateful.

Comment: I'm glad i was helpful. If you don't already you should look at regex testers, i like this one https://regex101.com/. They can make regular expressions much easier to work out and experiment with.